# Insert Album Artist tag using getid3()

Tags: php, id3, id3v2, getid3

I am using the getID3() library to insert the metadata into songs, that have no metadata.

I am able to insert all the tags except the Album Artist which is very important to me.

In demo.simple.write.php I have given the details of the songs like this:

```
$TagData = array(
'title'   => array('Emotion'),
'artist'  => array('Priyesh Vakil'),
'album'   => array('Radiance With Ragas Vol. 1'),
'year'    => array('2004'),
'genre'   => array('World Instrumental'),
'comment' => array('excellent!'),
'track'   => array('04/16'),
);
```

I tried adding:

```
'album_artist'   => array('Priyesh Vakil')
```

But it is not inserting anything in the Album Artist. Any idea how to insert this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `band` rather than `album_artist`.